# Is it possible to change the system date from Javascript(browser)?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am wondering if Date() can be hacked from changing system time?
Change system time (Manually set it) and then call Date() and will it return System date and time or the correct date and time, If it's not from the system then from where it's getting correct date and time?

Edit: In windows, if I set the time manually wrong then what are the chances to get the correct time?

Edit 2:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to change the system settings for that

Comment: Yes, a client-side date can be trivially changed. (So can a server-side one, but you're at least in control of that.) You cannot trust a date/time sent by a client outside of your control, so don't use it for something security-related.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Please write that in the answer and I will be glad to make it correct one.

Comment: thanks, @chris for comment, but my question was little programmatic instead of related to system settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a client-side date can be trivially changed. (So can a server-side one, but you're at least in control of that.) You cannot trust a date/time sent by a client outside of your control, so don't use it for something security-related.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful straight forward answer, looking forward to asking more questions on stack overflow.

Comment: I hope if i can upvote it but i can't right now.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you mean through the function Date.now()

Then this link might be helpful.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Reduced_time_precision

Comment: Pardon me. I mean for getting the whole date
`var d = new Date();
console.log(d)`